# Find and replace in DB string

Tags: regex, database, notepad++, phpstorm

I have a DB file. In that file there are many rows that contain phone number like this :

```
"a",93560050,"b"
```

I want to surround it with `""` to have it like this :

```
"a","93560050","b"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are phone numbers only numeric? No `+` or space or parenthesis? Is phone number the only number in a line?

Comment: @Toto yes only numeric. no in ever of per 2000 line there is one phone number like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to search like this:

```
(\d{8})
```

then you can replace with

```
"\1"
```

so you have the quotation.

Answer (score 2):

Because phone mumbers are only numeric and there're no other numbers than phone number, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+`
- Replace with: `"$0"`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>